# What's the integral of a constant?

Tags: calculus, integration

If the derivative of a constant is $0$ then what is the integral of a constant?

What is the integral of $0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral of a constant $C$ with respect to $x$ is $Cx + A$, $A$ constant. Applying this rule to the constant function $y(x) = 0$, $\int {0}dx = 0+A = A$.

Comment: @FuturePhdInMathematics $\frac{d}{dx} (Cx+A) = $?

Comment: OK... :) :) Thnxx

Comment: Integration is the inverse of differentiation, because that's how it's defined, so your question is equivalent to asking why is the differential of $y = Cx$ with respect to x C and why is the differential of $y = C$ with respect to x 0? In both cases the answer is because that's how diffentiation is defined: it's the rate of change of $y = f(x)$ with respect to x. We can see from the graph of $y = Cx$ that the rate of change is constant. To find out wha it is (in the case of $y = 4x$ say), we can just use any 2 points to calculate the gradient.

Comment: Taking (0,0) and (1,4), we find that the gradient $$m = \frac {x_2-x_1}{y_2-y_1} = \frac{4}{1} = 4. \\$$  (as expected). $$ \\ $$For $y = 0$, the rate of change of y with respect to x is clearly 0.

Answer (score 8):

Remember that the fundamental theorem of calculus says (essentially)

if $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ (i.e. $F' = f$), then $\int f = F + C$.

So, answer your own questions:

1) What kinds of functions have constants as their derivatives (i.e. given $f = $constant, what could $F$ be?)

2) What kinds of functions have $0$ as their derivatives (i.e. given $f = 0$, what could $F$ be?)

Answer (score -1):

You have to think about the $\frac{d}{dx}(nx)$ where $n$ is a constant. Then try integrating $n$ and see what you get.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).